# Is the phrase "Sanatana Dharma" (सनातन धर्म) found in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, identification-request

The phrase "*Sanatana Dharma*" seems to imply the eternal duties.

So, is the phrase found in the Vedas because I have seen many people saying that they are Sanatani and their religion is Sanatana Dharma?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Rig Veda 3.3.1](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv03003.htm)

> वैश्वानराय पृथुपाजसे विपो रत्ना विधंत धरुणेषु गातवे ।
> अग्निर्हि देवाँ अमृतो दुवस्यत्यथा **धर्माणि सनता** न दूदुषत् ॥
>
> vaishvAnarAya pRRithupAjase vipo ratnA vidhaMta dharuNeShu gAtave |
> agnirhi devAN amRRito duvasyatyathA **dharmANi sanatA** na dUduShat ||
>
> To him who shines afar, Vaisvanara, shall bards give precious
> thingthat he may go on certain paths: For Agni the Immortal serves the
> Deities, and therefore never breaks their **everlasting laws**.

[Manu Smriti 4.138](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200246.html)

> सत्यं ब्रूयात् प्रियं ब्रूयान्न ब्रूयात् सत्यमप्रियम् ।
> प्रियं च नानृतं ब्रूयादेष **धर्मः सनातनः** ।।
>
> satyaM brUyAt priyaM brUyAnna brUyAt satyamapriyam ।
> priyaM cha nAnRRitaM brUyAdeSha **dharmaH sanAtanaH** ।।
>
> He shall say what is true; and he shall say what is agreeable; he
> shall not say what is true, but disagreable; nor shall he say what is
> agreeable, but untrue; this is the **eternal law**.

[Srimad Bhagavatam 8.14.4](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/8/14/4/)

> चतुर्युगान्ते कालेन ग्रस्ताञ्छ्रुतिगणान्यथा ।
> तपसा ऋषयोऽपश्यन्यतो **धर्म: सनातन:** ।।
>
> chaturyugAnte kAlena grastAnChrutigaNAnyathA ।
> tapasA RRiShayo apashyanyato **dharmaH sanAtanaH** ।।
>
> At the end of every four yugas, the great saintly persons, upon seeing
> that the eternal occupational duties of mankind have been misused,
> reestablish the **principles of religion.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San%C4%81tan%C4%AB

Comment: Can you give an English translation of these verses. Only one is from vedas rest is from Smritis

Comment: @DarkKnight - Smritis are based on Vedas only, and agree with it 99.99%. So they cannot be discounted. There is no english equivalent for the word 'Dharma'. It is a mix of duty, law, religion, goal.

Comment: can you give the translation of rest of the words.

Comment: @mar Smritis are part of Vedangas (Kalpasutras) so inseparable from the Vedas. Most people don't understand this basic fact.

Comment: @Rickross yes you are correct, but my question was about vedas. And Smriti can contain fabrications. But vedas do not contain any fabrications.

Comment: @Rickross They choose not to understand because they hate the smritis.

Comment: No, I don't think it's just hate. Its lack of knowledge too. Most people think Sruti means word of God whereas Smriti means something that is written by men which is quite incorrect.@Ikshvaku

Comment: The RV Citation has nothing to do with Sanatana Dharma:  brererton and jamison:"1. To honor Vaiśvānara of broad visage, our inspired words offer him treasures so that he goes upon strong supports.Since immortal Agni befriends the gods, therefore, from of old, he has never corrupted the foundations (of the sacriﬁce)"

Comment: only the bhagavatam citation MAY have something with the sense "Sanatana Dharma" = "hinduism"

Comment: @SK - *he has never corrupted the foundations (of the sacriﬁce)* - that is what *Dharmani Sanata Na Dudushat* means. **Dharmani** - rules/yagna/sacrifice. **Sanata** - eternal/foundation/base. **Na** - Doesn't . **Dudushat** - Corrupt/Deny/Slander